# Nonlinear multilevel modeling with GAM(M)s: Which model to choose?

Tags: r, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I am attempting to understand the difference between three approaches for a GAM. My dataset (of which a subsample is included below) is longitudinal and hence is nested within-persons. I am predicting `Stress` over time based on the number of years someone is in a leadership position (`Time`), controlling for their gender (`Gender`), levels of trait extraversion (`Extraversion`), and trait neuroticism (`Neuroticism`). I have built three GAMs, one of which is a GAMM. My starting point was a linear multilevel model using the `lme4` package in `r`:

```
#Linear multilevel model.
    Model0 <- lmer(Stress~Time+Gender+Extraversion+Neuroticism+
                     (1|Person_ID), data=df2, REML=FALSE, na.action=na.exclude,
                   lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))
    summary(Model0)
    plot0 <- sjPlot::plot_model(Model0, type="pred")
    plot_grid(plot0)
```

But I want to check for nonlinear effects, hence the three versions I have built in the `mgcv` package in `r`:

```
#Single-level model.
Model1 <- gam(Stress~s(Time)+Gender+s(Extraversion)+s(Neuroticism),
              data=df2, method="REML", family=gaussian())
summary(Model1)
plot(Model1, shift=coef(Model1)[1], pages=1, all.terms=T, rug=F, residuals=F, se=T, shade=T, seWithMean=T)
vis.gam(Model1, view=c("Time","Extraversion"), plot.type="persp", color="topo", se=-1, theta=-20, phi=25)

#Model with random effect for Time specified via bs="re" argument.
Model2 <- gam(Stress~s(Time)+Gender+s(Extraversion)+s(Neuroticism)+s(Person_ID, bs="re"),
              data=df2, method="REML", family=gaussian())
summary(Model2)
plot(Model2, shift=coef(Model2)[1], pages=1, all.terms=T, rug=F, residuals=F, se=T, shade=T, seWithMean=T)
vis.gam(Model2, view=c("Time","Extraversion"), plot.type="persp", color="topo", se=-1, theta=-20, phi=25)

#Model with random effects for Time specified via random=list argument.
Model3 <- gamm(Stress~s(Time)+Gender+s(Extraversion)+s(Neuroticism), random=list(Person_ID=~1), data=df2)
summary(Model3$lme)
summary(Model3$gam)
plot(Model3$gam, shift=coef(Model3$gam)[1], pages=1, all.terms=T, rug=F, residuals=F, se=T, shade=T, seWithMean=T)
vis.gam(Model3$gam, view=c("Time","Extraversion"), plot.type="persp", color="topo", se=-1, theta=-20, phi=25)
```

What is the difference between the three? Which one should I use (or perhaps they are all wrong)?

Data:

```
df2 <- structure(list(Person_ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 
33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 
36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 
38L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 
44L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 52L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 56L, 57L, 
58L, 58L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 63L, 63L, 63L, 63L, 64L, 
65L, 65L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 67L, 67L, 68L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 
70L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 
73L, 73L, 74L, 74L, 75L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 79L, 80L, 
80L, 81L, 82L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 84L, 85L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 88L, 
89L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 91L, 92L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 96L, 
97L, 98L, 98L, 99L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 104L, 
105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 111L), .Label = c("100003", 
"100006", "100016", "100027", "100031", "100032", "100033", "100052", 
"100060", "100078", "100079", "100088", "100099", "100100", "100106", 
"100122", "100129", "100138", "100140", "100142", "100147", "100159", 
"100166", "100167", "100185", "100187", "100197", "100207", "100208", 
"100247", "100250", "100270", "100271", "100272", "100273", "100277", 
"100286", "100290", "100291", "100305", "100306", "100325", "100329", 
"100340", "100341", "100347", "100351", "100361", "100363", "100371", 
"100372", "100376", "100390", "100391", "100408", "100415", "100424", 
"100430", "100431", "100432", "100433", "100437", "100450", "100451", 
"100465", "100473", "100479", "100482", "100484", "100487", "100492", 
"100493", "100494", "100502", "1000034", "1000103", "1000136", 
"1000143", "1000166", "1000196", "1000215", "1000226", "1000255", 
"1000279", "1000281", "1000282", "1000320", "1000329", "1000383", 
"1000401", "1000411", "1000488", "1000496", "1000535", "1000632", 
"1000685", "1000732", "1000735", "1000736", "1000741", "1000758", 
"1000821", "1000825", "1000838", "1000870", "1000880", "1000882", 
"1000945", "1000993", "1001010", "1001036"), class = "factor"), 
    Time = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
    8L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
    11L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
    10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), Gender = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), Extraversion = c(4.33333333333333, 5.16666666666667, 
    4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 4.33333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 
    4.33333333333333, 3.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.33333333333333, 5, 4.33333333333333, 
    3.5, 3.5, 5.16666666666667, 5.16666666666667, 5.16666666666667, 
    5.16666666666667, 5.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 6, 
    6, 6, 2.83333333333333, 2.83333333333333, 2.83333333333333, 
    4, 4, 5.16666666666667, 5.16666666666667, 4.33333333333333, 
    4.33333333333333, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 5.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 
    5.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 6.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 
    6.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 5.33333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 
    5.33333333333333, 4, 4, 7, 4.16666666666667, 4.16666666666667, 
    3.66666666666667, 4.5, 5.16666666666667, 4.16666666666667, 
    4, 4, 4, 4.66666666666667, 5.33333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 
    4.33333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 5.5, 5.5, 4, 5.33333333333333, 
    6, 1.33333333333333, 2.83333333333333, 2.83333333333333, 
    2.83333333333333, 2.83333333333333, 4.16666666666667, 4.16666666666667, 
    4.16666666666667, 4.16666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 
    3.83333333333333, 3.83333333333333, 3.83333333333333, 5.83333333333333, 
    5.83333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 
    3.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 
    3.33333333333333, 3.83333333333333, 3.83333333333333, 5.83333333333333, 
    6.33333333333333, 6.33333333333333, 6.33333333333333, 6.33333333333333, 
    6.33333333333333, 6.33333333333333, 5.16666666666667, 5.16666666666667, 
    5.16666666666667, 6.83333333333333, 6.83333333333333, 6.83333333333333, 
    6.83333333333333, 5.16666666666667, 4, 5.66666666666667, 
    5.66666666666667, 5.66666666666667, 5.66666666666667, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5.66666666666667, 5.66666666666667, 5.16666666666667, 
    4.83333333333333, 4.83333333333333, 4.83333333333333, 4.83333333333333, 
    3.83333333333333, 3.83333333333333, 4.16666666666667, 4.16666666666667, 
    3.5, 3.5, 3.33333333333333, 3.83333333333333, 2, 2, 3.16666666666667, 
    6, 5.66666666666667, 5.66666666666667, 5.66666666666667, 
    4.16666666666667, 4.16666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 5.83333333333333, 
    5.83333333333333, 5.83333333333333, 6.66666666666667, 5.33333333333333, 
    5.33333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 2.16666666666667, 2.16666666666667, 
    2.16666666666667, 5.83333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 4.16666666666667, 
    3.33333333333333, 4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 
    4.66666666666667, 4.5, 4.66666666666667, 5, 3.5, 3.5, 4.16666666666667, 
    6.33333333333333, 6.33333333333333, 6.33333333333333, 4.66666666666667, 
    4.66666666666667, 3.16666666666667, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 3.5, 
    6.33333333333333, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 
    3.33333333333333, 3.33333333333333, 3.83333333333333, 3.83333333333333, 
    3.83333333333333, 3.83333333333333, 5.66666666666667, 5.66666666666667, 
    7, 7, 3.33333333333333, 4.16666666666667, 4.16666666666667, 
    5.66666666666667, 4.5, 4.5, 2.83333333333333, 2.83333333333333, 
    4, 4.33333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 3.16666666666667, 
    4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 5.33333333333333, 3.83333333333333, 6.83333333333333, 
    6.83333333333333, 4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 5.33333333333333, 
    4.16666666666667, 4.16666666666667, 4.16666666666667, 4.16666666666667, 
    6.33333333333333, 4.83333333333333, 4.83333333333333, 5.66666666666667, 
    4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 3.83333333333333, 5.33333333333333, 
    5.33333333333333, 6.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 5.66666666666667, 
    3.83333333333333, 4.83333333333333, 5.66666666666667, 4.5, 
    4.5, 4, 5.33333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 4.5, 3.5, 3.5, 
    2.5, 3.5, 3.5), Neuroticism = c(3.16666666666667, 3.33333333333333, 
    3.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 1.66666666666667, 
    1.66666666666667, 1.66666666666667, 2.16666666666667, 2.33333333333333, 
    2, 1.33333333333333, 1.33333333333333, 2.16666666666667, 
    2.16666666666667, 2.16666666666667, 2.16666666666667, 2.16666666666667, 
    2.16666666666667, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1, 1, 2.5, 2.5, 2.16666666666667, 
    2.16666666666667, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3.16666666666667, 3.16666666666667, 
    3.16666666666667, 3.16666666666667, 1.33333333333333, 1.33333333333333, 
    1.33333333333333, 1.33333333333333, 2.83333333333333, 2.83333333333333, 
    2.83333333333333, 3.5, 1.16666666666667, 3.5, 3, 4.33333333333333, 
    2.16666666666667, 2.33333333333333, 3.83333333333333, 2.5, 
    2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 2.66666666666667, 
    2.83333333333333, 4, 4, 4, 4.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, 
    1, 3.16666666666667, 4.33333333333333, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3.16666666666667, 
    3.16666666666667, 3.16666666666667, 3.16666666666667, 2.33333333333333, 
    2.33333333333333, 5.66666666666667, 5.66666666666667, 5.66666666666667, 
    2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 3.16666666666667, 3.16666666666667, 
    3.16666666666667, 3.16666666666667, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.66666666666667, 
    1.66666666666667, 1.5, 2.16666666666667, 2.16666666666667, 
    2.16666666666667, 2.16666666666667, 2.16666666666667, 2.16666666666667, 
    4.16666666666667, 5, 5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 4.66666666666667, 
    3.83333333333333, 5.66666666666667, 5.66666666666667, 5.66666666666667, 
    5.66666666666667, 2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 
    2.33333333333333, 2.16666666666667, 2.16666666666667, 1.5, 
    3.16666666666667, 3.16666666666667, 3.16666666666667, 3.16666666666667, 
    2.5, 2.5, 2.66666666666667, 2.66666666666667, 3.33333333333333, 
    3.33333333333333, 4.5, 5.5, 3.16666666666667, 3.16666666666667, 
    4, 2.66666666666667, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 4.33333333333333, 4.33333333333333, 
    1.5, 2.16666666666667, 2.16666666666667, 2.16666666666667, 
    2.16666666666667, 3.5, 3.5, 4.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3, 4.16666666666667, 
    2.5, 2.5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2.83333333333333, 2.66666666666667, 
    5.5, 3, 3, 2, 3.83333333333333, 3.83333333333333, 3.83333333333333, 
    2.83333333333333, 2.83333333333333, 2, 3.66666666666667, 
    3.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 2.66666666666667, 
    1.16666666666667, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.16666666666667, 2.16666666666667, 
    2.16666666666667, 2.16666666666667, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3.66666666666667, 
    3.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 4.16666666666667, 
    4.83333333333333, 4.83333333333333, 3.66666666666667, 2.5, 
    2.5, 2.16666666666667, 2.16666666666667, 2.33333333333333, 
    3.83333333333333, 3.83333333333333, 4, 3.33333333333333, 
    3.33333333333333, 3.83333333333333, 3.83333333333333, 4.83333333333333, 
    3.33333333333333, 1.66666666666667, 1.66666666666667, 2.16666666666667, 
    2.16666666666667, 4.33333333333333, 4.16666666666667, 4.16666666666667, 
    2.5, 2.5, 3, 1.33333333333333, 1.33333333333333, 2.33333333333333, 
    4.83333333333333, 4.83333333333333, 4.16666666666667, 1.5, 
    1.5, 2, 2, 3.5, 1.66666666666667, 3.66666666666667, 2.33333333333333, 
    2.83333333333333, 2.83333333333333, 4.5, 1.66666666666667, 
    3, 1.83333333333333, 2.66666666666667, 2.66666666666667, 
    5.66666666666667, 2.5, 2.5), Stress = c(2, 2.25, 3, NA, 4.25, 
    NA, NA, 3.25, 1, 2.5, 2, 3.75, 3.25, 3.25, 2.5, 2.5, 2, 3.75, 
    2.25, 2.25, 2, 1.75, 6, NA, 4.5, 5, 4.25, 3, 3, 2.5, 3, 3.75, 
    4, 4, 3.5, NA, NA, 4.75, 4.75, 5, 4, 6, 6.75, 5.5, 6, 3.25, 
    3.25, 4, NA, 2.5, 3.5, 3, 3.75, 2, 3, 5.25, 5, 3, NA, 1.75, 
    2.5, 3, 4, NA, 3, 3.75, 3, 2.75, 4.5, 6.25, 5.75, 4, 4.25, 
    3, 4.25, 5, 5.5, 5.75, 5, 4.5, 5, 2, 2, 2.75, 4, 2.5, 3.25, 
    3.75, 3.25, 3.75, 2.5, 4.5, 3.75, 4.25, 2.75, 3.75, 1.75, 
    3.5, 3.5, 4.5, 4, 4.75, 4.5, 2, 5.5, 5.25, 6, 5.25, 4, 6.75, 
    6, 3, 4, 5, 4.5, 6, 5, 3.25, NA, 3.25, 3.25, 3.5, 1.25, 3, 
    NA, 5, 3.5, 4.75, 4.25, 2.75, 4, 5, 4.5, NA, 3.5, 4.5, 5, 
    3.25, 5.75, NA, 3, NA, 3.25, NA, 2.5, 4, 6.5, 4, 3.75, 4.5, 
    5, 3, 3.5, 3.75, 4.25, 3.25, 4.5, 3.75, 4, 3.5, 5.75, NA, 
    4.25, 4.5, 3, 3, 3.75, 3.5, 2, 2.75, 4.25, 2.75, 2.75, 2.75, 
    6.25, 5.75, 2.5, 2.5, 1.75, 2.75, 2, 3.5, 3.75, 3.5, 3.25, 
    5, 4, 4.5, 4.25, 6, 5.5, 3.25, 2.5, 4.5, 6.25, 4, 3.25, 2.25, 
    4.25, 5.25, 3, 3.75, 4.25, 3.5, 4, 3, 5.25, 2.75, 4.25, 3.25, 
    5.5, 3.75, 3.25, 5.75, 4.25, 3.75, NA, 4, 3.75, 3.25, 4.75, 
    4.5, 5.25, NA, 1.5, 4.5, 4.25, 4.5, 4.25, NA, 3, 2.25, 3.5, 
    2, 4.25, 3, 4.5, 2.25, 4.5, 2.75, 5, 5.25, 3.75, 3.75, 2.5, 
    5, 4.25, 5.75, 2.5, NA)), row.names = c(4L, 5L, 11L, 10L, 
9L, 8L, 12L, 34L, 89L, 88L, 108L, 110L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 176L, 
177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 
270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 287L, 288L, 300L, 301L, 302L, 303L, 307L, 
306L, 308L, 309L, 310L, 311L, 312L, 313L, 324L, 323L, 322L, 333L, 
336L, 338L, 344L, 346L, 353L, 369L, 371L, 376L, 382L, 381L, 383L, 
391L, 396L, 412L, 411L, 410L, 413L, 414L, 415L, 439L, 446L, 463L, 
464L, 465L, 466L, 467L, 468L, 469L, 470L, 471L, 472L, 473L, 475L, 
474L, 476L, 478L, 477L, 492L, 491L, 490L, 493L, 494L, 495L, 496L, 
497L, 498L, 499L, 501L, 503L, 504L, 505L, 506L, 507L, 508L, 509L, 
527L, 528L, 529L, 530L, 531L, 532L, 533L, 534L, 546L, 547L, 548L, 
549L, 550L, 551L, 552L, 553L, 554L, 555L, 566L, 567L, 568L, 569L, 
570L, 571L, 572L, 577L, 578L, 583L, 584L, 585L, 586L, 589L, 588L, 
596L, 597L, 598L, 600L, 601L, 604L, 603L, 607L, 608L, 609L, 610L, 
627L, 636L, 639L, 643L, 645L, 646L, 647L, 655L, 656L, 657L, 660L, 
673L, 672L, 671L, 674L, 675L, 676L, 690L, 691L, 692L, 701L, 703L, 
702L, 704L, 707L, 708L, 709L, 713L, 714L, 715L, 716L, 717L, 723L, 
725L, 726L, 727L, 728L, 729L, 730L, 731L, 732L, 733L, 734L, 735L, 
736L, 737L, 739L, 7L, 6L, 23L, 27L, 26L, 33L, 36L, 35L, 47L, 
46L, 61L, 64L, 63L, 86L, 95L, 94L, 97L, 96L, 98L, 113L, 115L, 
114L, 141L, 140L, 143L, 145L, 144L, 172L, 171L, 173L, 187L, 186L, 
216L, 228L, 227L, 250L, 252L, 251L, 254L, 253L, 255L, 256L, 279L, 
280L, 282L, 281L, 283L, 289L, 290L, 297L, 305L, 304L, 314L, 319L, 
318L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Model1` is a GAM (or a penalized GLM with smooth terms).

`Model2` and `Model3` are equivalent mathematically, and practically equivalent up to implementational differences. (there's also the issue that `gamm()` defaults to fitting using maximum likihood, not REML, which you used in the `gam()` fit.)

The Bayesian view of smoothing, which you are using with `gam()` and `method = 'REML'` provides an equivalency between smooths and random effects; technically these are all just Gaussian random fields. So just as you can consider a model with smooth terms as a GLMM (a mixed effects model), you can view a GLMM as a GAM where the random effects are represented by identity matrices as the penalty matrices of "smooths".

It's better not to think about these models as unique types or species of model but as different facets of the same thing; otherwise you get twisted in all sorts of knots considering whether `Model2` is a GAM or a GAMM!

If you used a more general model fitting system like TMB or Stan (say via *brms*), all this distinctions disappear as you're just estimating a set of parameters by evaluating a likelihood (plus doing some MCMC in the case of Stan).

As to which model flavour or facet to use, if you have clustering at the subject level then `Model2` or `Model3` is the way to go as you should account for that clustering and `Model1` doesn't. Then which of those you use will depend on how much data you have and how many subjects you have; `gam()` is not as efficient at fitting random effects as *nlme* is and once you get over say 50-100 levels of the subject factor *nlme* and hence `gamm()` will be much more efficient. The downside is that `gamm()` is much harder to make work in complex model settings and is more likely to fail with warnings, convergence issues, etc than `gam()`.

Also consider `gamm4::gamm4()` which fits the models in a similar way to `gamm()` but which uses *lme4* and hence is much better for non-Gaussian models.

(Which you might consider here as the response `Stress` sounds like something that can only take positive values...)

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much. Your explanation is much appreciated. Indeed, your final point regarding non-Gaussian models for `Stress` is a good one. Thanks again.